# SFMC API authenication scope

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am using the api "guide/v1/emails/preview/send" which is not list in the REST API Permission IDs and Scopes page. Does anyone know what kind of scope I can use? Thanks.

I have refer this page https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_rest_permission_scopes/rest-permissions-and-scopes.html to check which scope I needed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjWI0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found that we can use approvals_write / approvals_read these scope.